# is there way store functions looping through them and putting them in a object

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

how can i sotre these function in object , looping through all of them and putting them in my storeObject

```
var fn1 = function1();
var fn2 = function2();
var fn3 = function3();
var fn4 = function4();


const store = {
    storeId : 1,
    cache:{},
    add:function(fn){
        if(!fn.id){
            fn.id = this.storeId++;
            this.cache[fn.id] = fn;
            return true;
        }
    }
}

for(let i = 0;i < 4;i++){
    store.add ?; // i got stuck here what i should i do in order to store my functions using the for loop
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap everything in an array for you to loop through. Like an array of Object

Becomes:

```
var fxns = [
{fn1: function1()},
{fn2: function2()},
{fn3: function3()},
{fn4: function4()}
]

for(let i = 0;i < fxns.length;i++) {
   
}
```

Comment: What you have stored in `fxns` are the _results_  returned from the 4 function calls at the beginning of your script and _not_ the functions themselves.

Comment: I thought the request was to loop through all of those functions.